# Getting right encoding for e-mail from gmail API

Tags: python, encoding, gmail-api, quoted-printable

I am struggling to get special characters from an email to display correctly.

I get the message using the Gmail API like this:

```
msg_id = '169a8fac44fd8115'
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg_id).execute()
htmlpart = message['payload']['parts'][0]['parts'][1]['body']['data']
```

I've then tried the following:

```
file_data = quopri.decodestring(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(htmlpart)).decode('iso-8859-1')
file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(htmlpart.encode('UTF-8')).decode('iso-8859-1')
file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(htmlpart.encode('iso-8859-1')).decode('utf-8')
file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(htmlpart.encode('UTF-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

None of them get me the right output. Instead I get things like `â‚¬2` instead of `€`.

For reference, the headers of this message are as follows:

```
'headers': [{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"'},
  {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value': 'quoted-printable'}]
```

Edit: added sample data below. I am trying to get the html of an e-mail, I am copying below just a part of it which highlights the encoding problem (`You&#39;ll get`).

```
</tr><tr><td class="m_4364729876101169671Uber18_text_p1" align="left" style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:&#39;Uber18-text-Regular&#39;,&#39;HelveticaNeue-Light&#39;,&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:28px;direction:ltr;text-align:left"> Give friends free ride credit to try Uber. You&#39;ll get CN¥10 off each of your next 3 rides when they start riding. <span class="m_4364729876101169671Uber18_text_p1" style="color:#000000;font-family:&#39;Uber18-text-Regular&#39;,&#39;HelveticaNeue-Light&#39;,&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:28px">Share code: 20ccv</span></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers

```
'headers': [{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"'},
  {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value': 'quoted-printable'}]
```

are telling you that the message consists of text encoded as UTF-8, then quoted-printable encoded so that it can be processed by systems that only support 7-bit characters.

To decode, you need to decode from quoted-printable first, and then decode the resulting bytes from UTF-8.

Something like this ought to work:

```
utf8 = quopri.decodestring(htmlpart)
text = ut8.decode('utf-8')
```

HTML email bodies may contain [character entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).  These can be converted to individual characters using [html.unescape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) (available in Python 3.4+).

```
>>> import html 
>>> h = """</tr><tr><td class="m_4364729876101169671Uber18_text_p1" align="left" style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:&#39;Uber18-text-Regular&#39;,&#39;HelveticaNeue-Light&#39;,&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:28px;direction:ltr;text-align:left"> Give friends free ride credit to try Uber. You&#39;ll get CN¥10 off each of your next 3 rides when they start riding. <span class="m_4364729876101169671Uber18_text_p1" style="color:#000000;font-family:&#39;Uber18-text-Regular&#39;,&#39;HelveticaNeue-Light&#39;,&#39;Helvetica Neue Light&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:28px">Share code: 20ccv</span></td>"""


>>> print(html.unescape(h))
</tr><tr><td class="m_4364729876101169671Uber18_text_p1" align="left" style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:'Uber18-text-Regular','HelveticaNeue-Light','Helvetica Neue Light',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:28px;direction:ltr;text-align:left"> Give friends free ride credit to try Uber. You'll get CN¥10 off each of your next 3 rides when they start riding. <span class="m_4364729876101169671Uber18_text_p1" style="color:#000000;font-family:'Uber18-text-Regular','HelveticaNeue-Light','Helvetica Neue Light',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:28px">Share code: 20ccv</span></td>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use this code it outputs a huge list of seemingly random characters (I guess it's base64). If I add base64 decoding like this: utf8 = quopri.decodestring(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(htmlpart))
file_data = utf8.decode('utf-8')
then it tells me UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 30992: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data that you're trying to decode?

Comment: Yes, added in the original post.